# Springboot Security how to get role inside "Principal"

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have this fonts

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("myRole")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
}
```

I know "hasRole" looks at permissions inside securityContext.authentication.authorities but is there a way for "hasRole" to another place?

My roles are inside securityContext.authentication.principal.attributes.role :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl6bC.png

I even created an endpoint that returns if the role I want exists, but I don't know how it would help me inside the "configure" method:

```
public boolean isAllowed() {
    UserAttributesDTO user = getUser();
    if (nonNull(user)) {
        return user.getRoles().stream().anyMatch(role -> role.equals("admin_cadastro_externo"));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you should probably not include images in your question. Most of the details of this question are inside that image, and it should be text in the question to be searchable.

Comment: Imho question is not clear. There is not any request when configure method runs so it will be empty. Also why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the built-in `oauth2Login()` and your principal is a `DefaultOidcUser`, you want to use `.hasAuthority("myAuthority")` instead. You can influence what authorities are present by providing a [`GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` as an `@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-grantedauthoritiesmapper).

If you must access the attributes in place, you may be interested in `.access(...)` using an `@Bean` reference.

See [Referring to Beans in Web Security Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html#el-access-web-beans). In that case, you should use the `authentication` passed to the method instead of the `SecurityContextHolder` to access the `authentication`.